# notary returns Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -r

Tags: notary

I want to use delegates with DOCKER CONTENT TRUST. I generated the delegate.crt/key on the collaborator's machine and now I am trying to rotate the snapshot key with:

```
notary key rotate localhost:5000/ubuntu snapshot -r

=> Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -r
Usage:
  notary key rotate [ GUN ] [flags]
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 8):

Had "unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -rm" error but due bad argument, not that I wanted delegation.

Was:

```
$ docker run -rm busybox echo hello world
```

Causing:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -rm
```

The correct parameter is `--rm` two dashes.

```
$ docker run --rm busybox echo hello world
```

> the --rm flag that can be passed to docker run which automatically
> deletes the container once it's exited from.

Source: https://github.com/prakhar1989/docker-curriculum#11-docker-run

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer: I know zilch about Docker Notary, so this might be completely bogus)*

According to the [Notary documentation](https://github.com/docker/notary/blob/master/docs/advanced_usage.md#rotate-keys):

> The root and targets key must be locally managed - to rotate either
>   the root or targets key, for instance in case of compromise, use the
>   notary key rotate command without the -r flag. The timestamp key must
>   be remotely managed - to rotate the timestamp key use the notary key
>   rotate  timestamp -r command.

So I'd guess you're trying to use a non-locally managed root or targets key which apparently is not supported.

Comment: Worked without the flag but I receive another error now: " "  when:

Comment: >notary delegation add localhost:5000/ubuntu targets/releases delegation.crt --all-paths => Error: unknown command "delegation" for "notary"

Comment: but I found that it's about the notary client version. Thank you for your replay!